# Getting a list out of a list comprehension with map

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to get numbers out of a list of strings. I used a list comprehension as shown below and then mapped the strings of the numbers to integers. I was hoping since it is in `[]` already to get the numbers, but it creates a list with a `map` object. The lower version gives the correct result, but it seems bloated to create the list and the unpack it immediately. Is there a more straight forward way to do this?

```
import re

list_of_strings = ['text...', 'text...', 'number, [10,20]', 'text...']

list_with_map = [map(int,re.findall("(\d+)", entry)) for entry in list_of_strings if entry[0] == 'n']
numbers = [list(map(int,re.findall("(\d+)", entry))) for entry in list_of_strings if entry[0] == 'n'][0]

print(numbers)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "create the list and the unpack it immediately"? Do you want to *flatten* the results?

Comment: You need to iterate over a map object to actually perform the mapping. Putting it inside a `list` constructor will do that.  
Your version creates a list of numbers for each string in the list of strings, so your output is a list of lists of ints. Are you sure you only want the first result from this? In that case you can use `next(map(...))`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi by that i mean, creating a list with 1 element and then get the single item with `[0]`. @b9s Yes, there will only be one so first would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `itertools.chain`:

```
list_of_strings = ['text...', 'text...', 'number, [10,20]', 
                   'text...', 'number, [30,40]'] 
# Added last element for demonstration

list(map(int, chain.from_iterable([re.findall("\d+", entry) for entry
                                  in list_of_strings if entry.startswith("n")])))
```

Output:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also give exactly what you are looking for ie. list of list of numbers.

```
import re
import ast
list_of_strings = ['text...', 'text...', 'number, [10,20]', 'text...']

numbers = [ast.literal_eval(s[s.find("["):s.find("]")+1]) for s in list_of_strings if s[0] == 'n']

print(numbers)
```